# Searching a 2d list in python for a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

```
tuple1 = [3,4]
list1 = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]

if tuple1 in list1 == True:
    print("tuple in list")
```

I would've thought that this should print, but it doesn't. Can anyone help?

Comment: You `tuple1` is a list

Comment: hint: `if something == True:` could be written as just `if something:`

Comment: Also, `tuple1 in list1 == True` is equivalent to `(tuple1 in list1) and (list1 == True)`, which will **always** be false, since `list1` is a `list`, and `list` objects are never equal to a boolean object. This is due to [comparison chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) which is there to allow you to write things like `3 <= x <= 10`

Answer (score 2):

You are not asking if a `tuple` is in your list, you are asking if a `list` is in your list.

```
>>> list1 = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
>>> [3,4] in list1
False
>>> (3,4) in list1
True
```

It works as you'd expect if you pass the correct type for `tuple1`.

Comment: There's actually a more subtle bug here.